# Open SSH from Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, scp

I've deployed on Heroku a worker who periodically uploads a file to a ssh server. It's wrote on Node.js and it does:

```
require('child_process').exec('scp -i id_rsa myfile.txt myuser@myserver.com:updated.txt', function() { ... });
```

In order to connect to the server the repository has a *id_rsa* file with a private key than is authorized by *myserver.com*. I've tested it on two computers (than has no key exchange with *myserver.com*) and it works, but when I upload it to Heroku it scp outputs:

```
Host key verification failed.
```

Why?

### NOTE

I've also tried instead of execute *scp*:

```
cat file.txt | ssh [myuser]@[myserver] "cat > updated.txt"
```

The same problem.

### UPDATE

Executing *ssh -v ...* it outputs:

```
[...]
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
[...]
```

I can't access tty on Heroku?

This are all the files on the repo:

## main.js

```
require('child_process').exec('scp -i id_rsa file.txt [myuser]@[myserver]:updated.txt', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
    if (error)
        console.error('FAILED', stderr.toString());
    console.log('OUTPUT', stdout.toString());
});
```

## id_rsa

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
[censored]
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

## package.json

```
{
    "name": "exta",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "engines": { "node": "0.6.x" }
}
```

## Procfile

```
worker: node main
```

## file.txt

```
Testing
```

Comment: have you tried https://github.com/mscdex/ssh2 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the problem, it was not on the RSA key but on the server key.

The first time a SSH connection is established between two computers SSH ask you yo add the server's key to *~/.ssh/known_hosts* in order to do this it tries to prompt it into the tty. As I've already accepted my server's key on my computers it didn't happen when I tested it locally.

As I'm not sure how to order my program to add the key to *~/.shh/known_hosts* I've tricked SSH to add the key without asking:

```
ssh -i id_rsa -o -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no [myuser]@[myserver]
```

As I don't want to touch Heroku's environment I've also asked ssh to store the keys on */dev/null* so nothing is modified:

```
ssh -i id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no [myuser]@[myserver]
```

And... IT WORKS! :D